# Sharepoint 2013 designer 3 stage workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, workflow2013, workflow-tasks-list

I am working on SharePoint 2013 on-premise environment. I have three-stage scenario. In each stage, approver have different inputs like

- First Stage approver identifies the request and if he feels it's applicable then he will assign to respective abc approver.
- In Second Stage abc approver checks type of request. If this request is under his zone then he will define his input (like the type of request, duration require) otherwise he will assign this task to center zone admin.
- In Third Stage center zone, the admin will check the request as per process he will follow some steps and provide the required information and then he can approve or reject.

So in each stage, the approver's input form is different so in this case what is the best approach? how can I create the different form on each stage or should I create different custom task list and anything else better solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom content types that inherit from the Workflow 2013 task content type, and add them to your tasks list.